# What is the relation between any suitable measure of model complexity, number of training examples and network size in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, training, models, sample-complexity

What is the relation between any suitable measure of model complexity, number of training examples and network size in deep learning?

Comment: Please name one such measure of model complexity, so we can elaborate from there.

Comment: Let us use VC complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the higher the model complexity, the more training examples (and computation time) is required for the model to learn.

In general, network size is directly proportional to model complexity. The larger the network size, the more parameters, thus higher the complexity.